# How can I use a keyword in the LATEX_HEADER?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have this `.org`-file (let’s call it `letter.org`):

```
#+AUTHOR: Me
#+SENDER: hu-berlin-letter-example
#+SUBJECT: Short description
#+LANG: de
#+ADDRESSEE: my adress

#+SETUPFILE: org-setupfile.org

Thank you very much for your letter.

THIS WORKS: {{{keyword(SENDER)}}}
ADDRESSEE: {{{keyword(ADDRESSEE)}}}
AUTHOR: {{{keyword(AUTHOR)}}}
THIS WORKS, TOO: \LoadLetterOption{ {{{keyword(SENDER)}}} }
```

My `org-setupfile.org` contains this:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results none :export none
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("hu-berlin-letter"
               "\\documentclass{hu-berlin-letter}
           [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
           [PACKAGES]
\\usepackage{hyperref}
           [EXTRA]"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
#+end_src

#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+LATEX_COMPILER: lualatex
#+LATEX_CLASS: hu-berlin-letter
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [{{{keyword(SENDER)}}}]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \LoadLetterOption{ {{{keyword(SENDER)}}} }
```

When I export it to a `.tex`-file (using DOOM Emacs with `SPC m e l l`) I get this result:

```
\documentclass[{{{keyword(SENDER)}}}]{hu-berlin-letter}
           \usepackage{hyperref}
           \LoadLetterOption{ {{{keyword(SENDER)}}} }
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Me},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 29.0.90 (Org mode 9.6.1)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
.... % deleted biblatex-part
\begin{document}

Thank you very much for your letter.

THIS WORKS: hu-berlin-letter-example
ADDRESSEE: my adress
AUTHOR: Me
THIS WORKS, TOO: \LoadLetterOption{ hu-berlin-letter-example }
\end{document}
```

My problem is that this documentclass depends on the `.lco`-file which I want to load with `\LoadLetterOption` (or as an option to the documentclass) - but I cannot pass the content of the keyword `SENDER` where I need it to be (which is `#+LATEX_HEADER: \LoadLetterOption{{{{keyword(SENDER)}}}}` or `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [{{{keyword(SENDER)}}}]`).

The macro `{{{keyword(SENDER)}}}` works fine in the main body, but not in the LaTeX header....

Comment: The only keywords where, on export, macros are expanded on the RHS are `TITLE`, `DATE` and `AUTHOR`. This is controlled by the `parse` setting in `org-export-options-alist`. You'd have to add entries to that list for the `LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS` and `LATEX_HEADER` keywords. That would be a start, but I don't know if it would be enough. Do `C-h f org-macro-replace-all` and check its last argument - then check how that last argument is calculated in `org-export--annotate-info`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didnt know about `org-export-options-alist`, I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Org-mode LaTeX exporter designed for letters. Read [Creating letters with KOMA-Script scrlttr2 and Org-mode](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html) for more details.

With this exporter, you can customize the look of your letter by writing your own LCO files and including them with the `#+LCO:` keyword.